# How to do pre-registration after publishing app

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

As the games with pre-registration option gains more user, I want my game to be in pre-registration section in play store. As my game is already in live(100% rollout) by mistake how can I make my game to be available for PRE-REGISTER in the play store? 
Do i have to unpublish my game and then start from the beginning to activate this option in google play console?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after releasing in production track there is no way to release in pre registration track and unpublishing and doing won't work neither.